# Como llamar a una función dentro de ella misma?

Tags: javascript

En un juego de laberinto inserte todo el código dentro de una función `playMaze()` y la ejecuto para correr el juego. Cuando el jugador gana se crea un botón para volver a reiniciar el juego sin tener que actualizar la página. Como puedo llamar a la misma función sin necesidad de usar `location.reload()`

```
function playMaze() {
  const { Engine, Render, Runner, World, Bodies, Body, Events } = Matter;

  const cellsHorizontal = 3;
  const cellsVertical = 3;
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;

  const unitLengthX = width / cellsHorizontal;
  const unitLengthY = height / cellsVertical;

  const engine = Engine.create();
  engine.world.gravity.y = 0;
  const { world } = engine;
  const render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine,
    options: {
      wireframes: false,
      width: width,
      height: height,
    },
  });
  Render.run(render);
  Runner.run(Runner.create(), engine);

  // Walls
  const walls = [
    Bodies.rectangle(width / 2, 0, width, 2, { isStatic: true }),
    Bodies.rectangle(width / 2, height, width, 2, { isStatic: true }),
    Bodies.rectangle(0, height / 2, 2, height, { isStatic: true }),
    Bodies.rectangle(width, height / 2, 2, height, { isStatic: true }),
  ];
  World.add(world, walls);

  // Maze generation

  const shuffle = (arr) => {
    let counter = arr.length;

    while (counter > 0) {
      const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

      counter--;

      const temp = arr[counter];
      arr[counter] = arr[index];
      arr[index] = temp;
    }

    return arr;
  };

  const grid = Array(cellsVertical)
    .fill(null)
    .map(() => Array(cellsHorizontal).fill(false));

  const verticals = Array(cellsVertical)
    .fill(null)
    .map(() => Array(cellsHorizontal - 1).fill(false));

  const horizontals = Array(cellsVertical - 1)
    .fill(null)
    .map(() => Array(cellsHorizontal).fill(false));

  const startRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * cellsVertical);
  const startColumn = Math.floor(Math.random() * cellsHorizontal);

  const stepThroughCell = (row, column) => {
    // If i have visted the cell at [row, column], the return
    if (grid[row][column]) {
      return;
    }
    // Mark this cell as being visited
    grid[row][column] = true;
    // Assemble randomly-ordered list of neighbors
    const neighbors = shuffle([
      [row - 1, column, "up"],
      [row, column + 1, "right"],
      [row + 1, column, "down"],
      [row, column - 1, "left"],
    ]);

    // For each neighbor...
    for (let neighbor of neighbors) {
      const [nextRow, nextColumn, direction] = neighbor;

      // See if that neighbor is out of bounds
      if (
        nextRow < 0 ||
        nextRow >= cellsVertical ||
        nextColumn < 0 ||
        nextColumn >= cellsHorizontal
      ) {
        continue;
      }

      // If we have visited that neighbor, continue to the next neighbor
      if (grid[nextRow][nextColumn]) {
        continue;
      }

      // Remove a wall from either horizontals or verticals
      if (direction === "left") {
        verticals[row][column - 1] = true;
      } else if (direction === "right") {
        verticals[row][column] = true;
      } else if (direction === "up") {
        horizontals[row - 1][column] = true;
      } else if (direction === "down") {
        horizontals[row][column] = true;
      }

      // Visit that next cell
      stepThroughCell(nextRow, nextColumn);
    }
  };

  stepThroughCell(startRow, startColumn);

  horizontals.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    row.forEach((open, columnIndex) => {
      if (open) {
        return;
      }

      const wall = Bodies.rectangle(
        columnIndex * unitLengthX + unitLengthX / 2,
        rowIndex * unitLengthY + unitLengthY,
        unitLengthX,
        5,
        {
          label: 'wall',
          isStatic: true,
          render: {
            fillStyle: 'red'
          }
        }
      );
      World.add(world, wall);
    });
  });

  verticals.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    row.forEach((open, columnIndex) => {
      if (open) {
        return;
      }

      const wall = Bodies.rectangle(
        columnIndex * unitLengthX + unitLengthX,
        rowIndex * unitLengthY + unitLengthY / 2,
        5,
        unitLengthY,
        {
          label: 'wall',
          isStatic: true,
          render: {
            fillStyle: 'red'
          }
        }
      );
      World.add(world, wall);
    });
  });

  // GOAL
  const goal = Bodies.rectangle(
    width - unitLengthX / 2,
    height - unitLengthY / 2,
    unitLengthX * 0.7,
    unitLengthY * 0.7,
    {
      label: 'goal',
      isStatic: true,
      render: {
        fillStyle: 'green'
      }
    }
  );
  World.add(world, goal);

  // BALL
  const ballRadius = Math.min(unitLengthX, unitLengthY) / 4;
  const ball = Bodies.circle(
    unitLengthX / 2,
    unitLengthY / 2,
    ballRadius, {
      label: 'ball',
      render: {
        fillStyle: 'blue'
      }
    });
  World.add(world, ball);

  document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    const { x, y } = ball.velocity;

    if(event.keyCode === 87) {
      Body.setVelocity(ball, { x, y: y - 5 });
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 68) {
      Body.setVelocity(ball, { x: x + 5, y });
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 83) {
      Body.setVelocity(ball, { x, y: y + 5 });
    }

    if(event.keyCode === 65) {
      Body.setVelocity(ball, { x: x - 5, y });
    }
  });

  // Win Condition
  Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', event => {
    event.pairs.forEach((collision) => {
      const labels = ['ball', 'goal'];

      if (
        labels.includes(collision.bodyA.label) &&
        labels.includes(collision.bodyB.label)
      ) {
        document.querySelector('.winner').classList.remove('hidden');
        world.gravity.y = 1;
        world.bodies.forEach(body => {
          if(body.label === 'wall') {
            Body.setStatic(body, false);
          }
        });
        const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => location.reload()); // Aquí quiero llamar a la función playMaze()
      }
    });
  });
}

playMaze();
```

Comment: Todo lo que sea eventos oyentes deberias sacarlos de esa funcion, pues estos deberian solo ser añadidos una vez, el resto yo creo que no habria problemas si es que lo vuelves a ejecutar dentro del evento oyente del boton de reiniciar, de todas maneras no he usado mucho matter.js porque estoy 100% seguro de que eso es matter.js, pero que pasa si intentas reiniciar de nuevo los valores de matter.js?, intentalo.

Comment: @Riven hace muy bueno comentarios, no puedes simplement invocar `playMaze()` otra ves por que vas a crear otra instancia de `matter.js` ademas de los eventlisteners. Yo te recomendaria crea una funcion de setup de Matterjs la cual pase sus argumentos a la funcion `playMaze()` y luego otra funcion `resetMaze()` cuyo objectivo sea reiniciar variables y Matterjs entre otras la cual puedes invocar como callback del click event.